# NullPointerException BeforeInsert on Lead Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, null-pointer

I am pretty new to writing custom code in SF and would appreciate any help.  I have a trigger on Leads to update Status to "Contacted" when a task on that Lead is "Completed".  I found this in a similar post on Stack Exchange and made some modifications to fit my org.  **Trigger and test class below:**

```
trigger changeLeadStatus on Task (before insert, before update) {

    String desiredNewLeadStatus = 'Contacted';
    List<Id> leadIds=new List<Id>();
    for(Task t:trigger.new){
        if(t.Status=='Completed'){
            if(String.valueOf(t.whoId).startsWith('00Q')==TRUE){//check if the task is associated with a lead
                leadIds.add(t.whoId);
            }//if 2
        }//if 1
    }//for
    List<Lead> leadsToUpdate=[SELECT Id, Status FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :leadIds AND IsConverted=FALSE];
    For (Lead l:leadsToUpdate){
        l.Status=desiredNewLeadStatus;
    }//for

    try{
        update leadsToUpdate;
    }catch(DMLException e){
        system.debug('Leads were not all properly updated.  Error: '+e);
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest
private class LeadStatusTest {

    static testMethod void testTaskCompletionEvent(){
        // Create a lead record
        Lead newLead = new Lead() ; 
        newLead.LastName = 'Yang' ; 
        newLead.Company = 'Freedom Dividend' ; 
        newLead.Status = 'Prospect' ;
        insert newLead;     

        // Create a task record
        Task t = new Task() ; 
        t.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId() ; 
        t.Subject = 'Cash for all' ; 
        t.Status = 'Completed' ; 
        t.Priority = 'High' ; 
        t.whoid = newLead.id ; 
        insert t ; 
    }
}
```

The trigger has been deployed and is working in Production, with the exception of one use case.  Some of our Users keep track of their activities by BCC'ing SF.  In return, they are receiving the message below:

[image]

Any insight to why this happening or what I can do to fix this would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Probably not a solution to the error, but the code `if(String.valueOf(t.whoId).startsWith('00Q')==TRUE){` would be far better as `if (t.whoId != null && t.whoId.getSObjectType() == Lead.SObjectType) {`

Comment: @Brandon Just a side comment: even if the trigger is "technically" working, it should have been on `after insert` and `after update` events, because you need to ensure tasks are saved in database before processing logic on other records (lead). You can read more about this [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) and it is also a best practice to keep trigger logic-less by calling an apex class to perform the main logic. Read more about trigger best practices [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `Task` where `WhoId` is blank. In that case, you would get the error mentioned.

Instead of:

```
if(String.valueOf(t.whoId).startsWith('00Q')==TRUE)
```

Use:

```
if (t.WhoId != null && t.WhoId.getSObjectType() == Lead.sObjectType)
```

Please note that you should never compare a `Boolean` to `true`, neither in code nor in formulas.

Comment: Lead.SObjectType?

Comment: Just goes to show why this approach is so much better than prefix comparison.

Comment: Yours be better... sobject type wins :)

Comment: I totally agree with it - see my comment on the question...

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson.  Noted on comparing Boolean to true/false.